# Proportional Hazards, Competing Risks, or something else?

Tags: survival, hazard, proportional-hazards, competing-risks

I'm looking to do a time-to-event analysis.  My data set set has a binary response variable representing 2 distinct outcomes, a time variable, and some censoring.  I am mainly interested in the time to success.

The two outcomes are opposite and mutually exclusive.  It does not make sense to think of the events as different kinds of failures, it is more like one event represents success and one represents failure.  Due to this, competing risk models do not seem to be indicated as a cumulative incidence function would not make sense in this context.

With that said, it does not seem right to me to censor one of the outcomes and proceed with a standard proportional hazards model either.

Should I use:

a) A Proportional Hazards model, censoring the failures?

b) A competing Risks model?

c) A different kind of model?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe these data in any greater detail? I am not clear what you mean. Is this some kind of recurrent event? Like the pass/fail status of an exam? How can they have different event times if they are "opposite and mutually exclusive" as you say?

Comment: It is loan applications.  There are actually 3 outcomes.  I'm lumping the last two together.  Consumer gets a loan, bank denies loan to consumer, after submitting the application the consumer decides they no longer want the loan.

Comment: Then there is no censoring whatsoever. There are 2 time to event analyses: time until offer of the loan, and then time until consumer decision. Just use Poisson or logistic regression.

Comment: Sorry, I submitted the comment before I intended to.

It is loan applications. There are actually 3 outcomes. I'm lumping the last two together.

1) Bank approves the application and the consumer gets a loan.

2) Consumer does not get a loan. 
2a) Bank denies application.
2b) After submitting the application the consumer cancels the application.

I've already modeled the likelihood of these outcomes using Decision Trees, Neural Networks, and Logistic Regression.  

I'm also interested in the time component, which made me think Survival, PH, Competing Risks.

Comment: There is censoring, because some of the loans in the data set were still in progress so the outcome was unknown.

Also, 

2c) Sometimes the consumer doesn't actually cancel the application, they just stop communicating with the bank.  The bank eventually removes the application from their pipeline.  

Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Proportional hazards models are exactly about *getting rid* of the time component. If you want to model time (e.g. loans that take a long time to prepare an offer are more likely to be denied), include it as a fixed effect in the GLM.

Comment: I appreciate you responding so quickly. 

The proportional hazards do not depend on time. However, using a PH model, you can build these nice predicted survival curves for individual observations based on multiple predictors, predict how the probability of an application becoming a loan changes over time. This is what I was hoping to be able to produce.  

If it can't be done that's fine. I'll look into adding time as a variable in another model.